# Launch bat. for QGIS 3 python not working

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, bat

I'm trying to build a launch.bat for qgis 3 python. I would want to run python via batch file but I get an error 'no module named processing'

Launch.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

python D:\Testi2\testi.py
```

pause

Is the problem within those CALL batch files?

---

I think the problem might be in the python file I'm trying to run:

```
    from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingOutputNumber,
                       QgsProcessingParameterDistance,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination,
                       QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination)
import processing

etc.
```

I also tried adding..

```
# Prepare the environment
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\OSGeo4W64\bin', True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingOutputNumber,
                       QgsProcessingParameterDistance,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination,
                       QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination)
import processing
```

But it doesn't start qapplication via Pygt5.gtgui

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the python path to processing:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing;%PYTHONPATH%
```

Comment: now I get an error ' no module named qgis'. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't use QGIS on Windows (I use Linux), but in QGIS, click Plugins menu->Python Console and run `import os,sys;print(sys.path);print(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(qgis.__file__)))` to figure out the paths you need to add to `PYTHONPATH` in your batch file.